# Command line equiv to print a .docx file from Mac OS X finder

Tags: macos, bash, pdf, printing, ms-word

I have an application need to print a MS Word .docx file from the command line.  The background is this is on Snow Leopard Server with CUPS-PDF as the default printer. If in the finder I click once on the .docx file to select and then select print from the file menu it opens MS Word (2011 is installed) and prints the file to the spool (via CUPS) in PDF format. Perfect! Now what is the BASH command equivalent of that???

I have tried lpr, which only appears to work with straight text files. I have tried OPEN which OPENS MS Word but I see no "print" option for open. I have tried the usual MS Office equivalent (OpenOffice and LibreOffice) which both work but the generated PDF layout is so far from that generated by Word that it is shamefully unacceptable. I tried using osascript = AppleScript = which works  but is spotty - it does not always trigger.

My challenge is I am creating the .docx outside of word from a template with a PHP program and just need to convert it to PDF retaining all formatting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at `launch`, available here: http://sabi.net/nriley/software/, also easy to install using homebrew or macports.

It is like `open`, but adds some extra features, including

```
-p       Ask application(s) to print document(s).
```

Comment: I ended up using launch with a combination of that and `PDFwriter` to make this work.

Comment: Note that you can use `appswitch` (available at the same place — disclaimer, I wrote `launch` and `appswitch`) to quit applications a bit more gracefully, e.g., `appswitch -qi com.microsoft.Word`.  That way you don't have to contend with the crash reporter either :-)

Comment: I'm finding that `launch -p` opens the document in Chrome but doesn't trigger display of the print dialog.

Comment: this is amazing.  @NicholasRiley , you're my hero for those command line tools

Comment: @TJChambers could you please explain how you ended up solving this?

Answer (score 3):

If you have the Automator action `"Convert Format of Word Document"` installed, you could write an Automator workflow and then try to use the `automator` command line tool (see `man automator`).

Further information:

- [Automator Tip of the Week #3: Convert Word Documents to PDF](http://www.maciverse.com/automator-tip-of-the-week-3-convert-word-documents-to-pdf.html)
- [How to Batch Convert DOC files to PDF format Using Mac OSX Automator](http://aseriesoftubes.com/articles/how-to-batch-convert-doc-files-to-pdf-format-using-mac-osx-automator/)

Another option might be to use `PDFwriter for Mac` (hosted on sourceforge) or `CUPS-PDF for Mac OS X` (by codepoetry) and then use the command line ...

```
 # cf. http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-apps-games/212770-how-print-files-preview-pdf-command-line.html
lpstat -v | awk '{ print $3; }'
lpr -P <printer name> /path/to/file
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to convert a MS Word .docx document into a PDF file on Mac OS X would be to use the `qlmanage` command that ships with Mac OS X.

`qlmanage` can be used to transform a .docx document into a directory that contains a `Preview.html` file, a `PreviewProperties.plist` file and perhaps some dumped attachment files. After tweaking `Preview.html` a bit, a PDF file can be generated by using `wkhtmltopdf` (or `wkpdf` or `prince`).

For more information see:

- [Create PDFs with QuickLook](http://reganmian.net/wiki/create_pdfs_with_quicklook)
- [doc2pdf](http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/14630)

Answer (score 2):

OP's solution extracted from question:

> using launch and PDFwriter with the Ruby Script below.
>
> ```
> require 'rb-fsevent'
>
> paths = ['/private/var/hosts/toPDF']
> options = {:latency => 5, :no_defer => true }
>
> fsevent = FSEvent.new
> fsevent.watch paths, options do |directories|
>   Dir['/private/var/hosts/toPDF/*.docx'].each do |f|
>     puts 'processing '+f
>     system( "launch -p "+f)
>   end
>
>   sleep 30
>   system("killall -u tj 'Microsoft Word'")
>   system("killall -u tj 'Microsoft Error Reporting'")
> end
> fsevent.run
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `docx2pdf` tool to convert a docx file to pdf retaining all formatting. It works on macOS and Windows and requires Microsoft Word to be installed.

```bash
pip install docx2pdf
docx2pdf input.docx output.pdf
```

Disclaimer: I wrote the docx2pdf tool. https://github.com/AlJohri/docx2pdf

Comment: perhaps you could explain how to install Microsoft Word on Linux. The repo page does not.

Comment: @TJChambers I meant to write macOS and Windows, not Linux- I updated the answer. The tool tries to make a lossless, faithful conversion and thus requires Microsoft Word to be installed. Maybe you can install Word on Linux using Wine or Crossover?

Comment: @AlJohri can docx2pdf adjust the page margins and overall layout?