# python: unable to find files in recently changed directory (OSx)

Tags: python, macos, blocking

I'm automating some tedious shell tasks, mostly file conversions, in a kind of blunt force way with os.system calls (Python 2.7).  For some bizarre reason, however, my running interpreter doesn't seem to be able to find the files that I just created.

Example code:

```
import os, time, glob

# call a node script to template a word document
os.system('node wordcv.js')

# print the resulting document to pdf
os.system('launch -p gowdercv.docx')

# move to the directory that pdfwriter prints to
os.chdir('/users/shared/PDFwriter/pauliglot')

print glob.glob('*.pdf')
```

I expect to have a length 1 list with the resulting filename, instead I get an empty list.

The same occurs with

```
pdfs = [file for file in os.listdir('/users/shared/PDFwriter/pauliglot') if file.endswith(".pdf")]
print pdfs
```

I've checked by hand, and the expected files are actually where they're supposed to be.

Also, I was under the impression that os.system blocked, but just in case it doesn't, I also stuck a `time.sleep(1)` in there before looking for the files.  (That's more than enough time for the other tasks to finish.)  Still nothing.

Hmm.  Help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a wait after the call to `launch`.  Launch will spawn the task in the background and return before the document is finished printing.  You can either put in some arbitrary `sleep` statements or if you want you can also check for file existence if you know what the expected filename will be.

```
import time
# print the resulting document to pdf
os.system('launch -p gowdercv.docx')
# give word about 30 seconds to finish printing the document
time.sleep(30)
```

Alternative:

```
import time
# print the resulting document to pdf
os.system('launch -p gowdercv.docx')
# wait for a maximum of 90 seconds
for x in xrange(0, 90):
    time.sleep(1)
    if os.path.exists('/path/to/expected/filename'):
        break
```

Reference for potentially needing a longer than 1 second wait [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879917/command-line-equiv-to-print-a-docx-file-from-mac-os-x-finder)

Comment: wow, it really was that simple.  I feel dumb now.  :-)  thanks!