# Print a .docx file in Mac OS X using Python

Tags: python, macos, ms-word, docx, zebra-printers

I'm trying to print a docx file containing 2 images with Python but can't seem to figure this one out.

For context, it's the last part of a personal project which will be a booth where users complete a quiz, and then can print a personalized card.

Printer is a Zebra ZXP Series 3.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
with open("FILENAME.docx") as f:
# call the system's lpr command
p = Popen(["lpr"], stdin=f, shell=True)
output = p.communicate()[0]
```

It crashes the printer and makes it restart.

I found the code below which would be perfect but it is for Windows, it relies on the win32com library:

```
from win32com import client
    import time
    word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")
    def printWordDocument(filename):
        word.Documents.Open(filename)
        word.ActiveDocument.PrintOut()
        time.sleep(2)
        word.ActiveDocument.Close()
    word.Quit()
```

Any pointers to make this work on MacOs?

Thank you!

(This is my first question, I usually find answers by doing research on this site but I'm a bit stuck with this one)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879917/command-line-equiv-to-print-a-docx-file-from-mac-os-x-finder

Comment: Thanks Martheen. Looking into Launch now.

Comment: @Martheen Launch seems to be working but only when i call it from the terminal. Once I call it from the button press, it does nothing, and the error log shows: '-p: launch: command not found'

Comment: Got it to almost work (thank you Martheen and Nicholas from Launch): Needed to use the full path to launch, i.e. /usr/local/bin/launch.
And switched to subprocess.call.